# Georeferencing help (GeoTiff into MapWindow6)

Tags: c#, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, mapwindow

I'm a newbie with MapWindow6 and I would like to figure out a couple of things.
1 - Whenever I drag and drop a GeoTiff into the map (MapWindow6) I can not see that image at its place, I mean that Image is not georeferenced, so if I put another GeoTiff the latter overlaps the first one.
With MapWindow4 it was quite simple after creating an instance for the grid raster.
2 - Is there any particular way to implement DotSpatial in my project? I'm using Visual Studio 2005.
Any tips would be really appreaciated.
Thanks a lot guys,
Carmelo

Answer (score 1):

I found some useful information about your question about Dotspatial

https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial